# Groove LCD RGB I2C protocol

Tags: hd44780

Devices:

- RapberryPi 3 Model B+
- [GrovePi+](https://www.seeedstudio.com/GroveP-p-2241.html)
- [Grove LCD RGB](http://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Grove-LCD_RGB_Backlight/)

As a learning exercise, I'd like to write a driver for the LCD listed above.

I'm using the [HD44780](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitachi_HD44780_LCD_controller#Instruction_set) instruction set as reference, and can understand the 8-bit commands needed to control the display, eg `0x01` to clear the display. Furthermore, I can relate all the commands listed in this [driver source](https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/Grove_LCD_RGB_Backlight/blob/73f94d908d2fff91c49a39ecbbd74fc0d0e143ff/rgb_lcd.h#L58-L93) back to the instruction set.

My confusion is around the leading byte the library sends:

- [`0x80`](https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/Grove_LCD_RGB_Backlight/blob/73f94d908d2fff91c49a39ecbbd74fc0d0e143ff/rgb_lcd.cpp#L258-L262) for "commands"
- [`0x40`](https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/Grove_LCD_RGB_Backlight/blob/73f94d908d2fff91c49a39ecbbd74fc0d0e143ff/rgb_lcd.cpp#L265-L271) for "data"

Experimentally, I can see that `0x80` is required before any of the instruction commands, and `0x40` for text to be displayed.

My question is: where are these two values (`0x80` & `0x40`) defined in the spec? Without existing driver sources, how would one know to use those seemingly magic bytes?

Comment: Those 'specs' are buried in datasheets from decades ago when the famous HD44780 IC first came to market. For a given text LCD display you often need several datasheets to cover all the issues.

Comment: it is not related to the HD44780 IC ..... it is related to the JDH1313M1 controller .... the 0x80 and 0x40 have something to do with the I2C  ..... found this https://web.archive.org/web/20160412072121/http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/images/0/03/JHD1214Y_YG_1.0.pdf

Comment: "Spec"? What is "spec"? You are buying from a Chinese company targeting hobbyists. Your job is to carefully search through whatever you can get from them, and try to reverse-engineer what it is you've actually bought. Good luck. ;-)

(Seriously though, it looks like @jsotola has found the datasheet you need, which was once on the seeedstudio wiki but has been deleted. Your 0x80 is a "control byte" with "Co=1", indicating one data byte follows and then another control byte; your 0x40 is a "control byte" with "Co=0", indicating multiple data bytes follow, and "RS=1" (see instr. set. table.)

Comment: Thanks, the linked JDH1313M1 controller doc was helpful.